# Fiori analytical list page : UI.Chart format y axis/aggregrated property to integer only

Tags: sap-fiori, cds

I am new to ALP. I would like to format the y axis values to Integer only, no decimals.

[ALP chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIPmZ.png)
Total Number is defined as the AggregratedProperty as follows:

`Analytics.AggregatedProperty #totalNumber: { $Type : 'Analytics.AggregatedPropertyType', AggregatableProperty : sId, AggregationMethod : 'countdistinct', Name : 'totalNumber', ![@Common.Label]: 'Total Number' }`
"sId" is a String and the aggregratable property here.
Your answer would be much appreciated.
thanks!

I would like to display only integers on the y-axis. As there is no possibility in our scenario for values to be anything other than an integer.
I couldn't find a way to do so.